# Call exported function koajs

Tags: node.js, koa

I have a `koa` app which has a bunch of functions split up into separate files. When one route is called I need to pass the context `this` to another function (which is also a route) in an separate file.

File `a.js` route - `http://127.0.0.1:3000/foo`

```
exports.foo = function *() {
  this.body = 'Some Value';
}
```

File `b.js`route - `http://127.0.0.1:3000/bar`

```
var a = require('a');

exports.bar = function *() {
  this.body = yield a.foo(); // this obviously doesn't work.
}
```

I want to be able to `yield a.foo()` with the current context (`this`) and have it operate like it is being called by the normal router.

Comment: I think your shared functionality is better placed in a middleware where both `/foo` and `/bar` routes can call `yield this.sharedFeature(opts)`. If you want to go your way, then just do `yield a.foo.bind(this)`

Comment: Hmmmm, @kilianc seems like doing `yield a.foo.bind(this)` doesn't actually call the function nor return from the function? Is there something special you need to do in `a.foo` ?

Comment: a.foo is a generator right? then you don't have to do anything in particular, try `a.foo.call(this)` but `.bind` should work too

Comment: @kilianc you were right, that actually works. If you put that as an answer I will accept. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your shared functionality is better placed in a middleware where both `/foo` and `/bar` routes can call yield `this.sharedFeature(opts)`.

If you want to go your way, then just do `yield a.foo.call(this)`

Comment: `yield a.foo.call(this)` is better. no need to bind

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems there. one is you have to return the value (or pass the value back in the callback).  Also there is a problem how a.js is required.  You need to add the path to it "./a" (or where ever you store it), not "a".  Here is the revision (Note that I'm not including koajs in the code since this is just javascript/nodejs issue):

```
// a.js
exports.foo = function() {
  this.body = 'Some Value';
  return this;
}

// b.js
var a = require('./a');  // assumes a.js is in same directory as b.js

exports.bar = function () {
  var aThis =a.foo(); 
  console.log(aThis.body);
};

// c.js
var b = require('./b');

b.bar();   // <<<<< prints "Some Value"
```

This is how the context of bar() can be passed to foo():

```
// a.js
exports.foo = function(bScope) {
  console.log("this is bValue of b scope: %s", bScope.bValue);
}

// b.js
var a = require('./a');

exports.bar = function () {
  this.bValue = "value of b";
  a.foo(this);
}

// c.js
var b = require('./b');

b.bar();   // <<<<<<<< prints "this is bValue of b scope: value of b"
```

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, specifically I need the context from bar to be passed to foo. Regarding how `a` is required, its just an example.

Comment: Ok, I'll revise the answer for that